# Debugging previous entries in partially filled list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pdb

I am currently debugging a function (`produceEntry`) whose results are stored in a list comprehension:

```
entries = [produceEntry(i) for i in range(i)]
```

The error in the function manifests in one of the middle entries and I would like to inspect the previous entries but I cannot get access.

Obviously, I can restructure the code to

```
entries = []
for i in range(i):
    entries.append(produceEntry(i))
```

but I'd much rather like to not change the code only for debugging purposes.

Is there any way to access the already processed entries in the list comprehension?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the debugger treats that as one logical operation. Why not look inside the function you're calling instead?

Comment: @jonrsharpe looking into the function does not offer enough context. I need the results from the previous invocations. But I cannot set a break point in the function as it is called thousands of times without an error.

Comment: Why do you need that? Does your function somehow depend on the result so far? I don't think you can even access them.

Comment: I want to inspect whether the previous call to the function returned a correct result or leads to the error in the next call. Independently of that I feel it is a limitation to not be able to inspect the results of the comprehension so far as they must be available somewhere.

Comment: How would that happen? Is your function stateful, does it have side effects? It's not a limitation of a list comprehension, it's a *trade off*; if you're not prepared to make it, unroll the loop.

Comment: The function reads entities from a file and is therefore stateful. I don't have much insight into the internals of the python interpreter/debugger but I feel that it should be possible to get access to the list that has been built up so far. To me it does not seem like there should be a trade off at all: What do I get for not being able to inspect?

Comment: A performance improvement by pushing the process down from Python into the implementation (e.g. C), which is why the debugger can't step into it. It's faster than the equivalent loop appending to a list, but that's the price you pay.

Answer (score -1):

As *jonrsharpe* already stated, a list comprehension should be treated as a single operation, so you will not be able to access partial results.

In your case, you could for example catch your error and replace it with an error flag:

```
def produceEntry(i):
    try:
        return 1 / (5 - i)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 'ERROR'

entries = [produceEntry(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Printing entries, the output will look like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 'ERROR', -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Here the fifth i has produced a ZeroDivisionError, but has been replaced with 'ERROR' instead. Now you can tinker with the partial entries, and when you are done debugging simply change the exception handling according to your use-case. Your actual code remains unchanged.

Comment: The idea about a debugger is to be able to interact with the state at the error location. This is totally lost when having to wait for the whole comprehension to complete.